# PGobject type conversion in Clojure

Tags: clojure, type-conversion, hugsql

I'm having trouble with a type conversion problem in Clojure, using Hugsql. I'm new to Clojure and newer to SQL, and I'd appreciate any help I can get.

We recently migrated our PostgreSQL db so one column is a json array instead of a string -- the migration looks like:

`ALTER TABLE customers ALTER id TYPE JSON USING json_build_array(id);`

But now when I make query for that data, the type is a PGobject and not a collection like I was hoping. While I'm looking for:

- `["id-123"]`

the actual returned value is

- `#object[org.postgresql.util.PGobject 0x7ff0434e "[\"id-123\"]"]`

I spent some time looking up how to do the type conversion, but had no luck. How can I convert the type of this response to a collection or sequence in Clojure? 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that this is much easier than I was making it out to be.

You can just use `(.getValue my-pgobject)` and it  will be converted to a string like:

`"[\"id-123\"]"`, which can then be parsed with something like [cheshire.core/parse-string](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire#decoding)

Comment: I was able to use `(str my-pgobject)` to get the value as well!